# How to provide routerLink in Parent component for shared components

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters, routes, routerlink

I am building this app in angular 6 which uses [Rest Country API](https://restcountries.eu/) to fetch all the countries and their details.
The problem I am facing is that I am not able to understand how to set `routerLink` in the parent component in order to fetch the details of the countries.
Any suggestions would be appriciated.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

> I am not able to understand how to access the name of the country in
>   order to pass it to the URL. I tried almost everything I can think of but nothing seems to work.

Here are my files:

shared.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CountryViewComponent } from './country-view/country-view.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CountryViewComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    CountryViewComponent,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**Child Component**

country-view.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

// importing route related code
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

//importing Service related code
import { CountryViewService } from '../../country-view.service';
import { CountryViewHttpService } from '../../country-view-http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-country-view',
  templateUrl: './country-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country-view.component.css']
})

export class CountryViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() currentCountryName: String;

  public currentCountry;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private countryViewHttpService: CountryViewHttpService) {
    console.log("Contry View Constructor  Called");
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    // getting the name of the country from the route
    let myCountryName = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('currentCountryName');
    console.log(myCountryName);


    this.countryViewHttpService.getSingleCountryInfo(myCountryName).subscribe(

      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.currentCountry = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log("some error occured");
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("Country View Component Destroyed");
  }
}
```

**Parent Component HTML**

africa.component.html:

```
<!--Home page Html-->
<div class="container-fluid mainContainer">
  <div class="row mainRow">
    <div class="col mainCol">

      <!--Content Section-->
      <div class="row africanCountryRowHeading">
        <div class="backArrow">
          <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
            <i class="material-icons">
              keyboard_backspace
            </i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 upperCol">AFRICA</div>
      </div>

      <a [routerLink]="['/country']">
        <div class="row africanCountryRowContent" *ngIf="allAfricanCountries.length>0">
          <div *ngFor="let africanCountry of allAfricanCountries" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 africanCountriesMainCol">

            <!--Country Iteration div starts here-->
            <div class="row africanCountriesRow">
              <div class="col-md-12 africanCountryCol">
                <div class="panel-flag africanCountriesFlag">
                  <img [src]="africanCountry.flag">
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default africanCountriesPanel">
                  <div class="panel-heading africanCountriesPanelHeading">Country: {{africanCountry.name}}</div>
                  <div class="panel-body africanCountriesPanelBody">
                    <p>
                      Capital: {{ africanCountry.capital }}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Countries Iteration div ends here-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Parent Component Module file**

africa.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CountryViewComponent } from '../shared/country-view/country-view.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'country/:name', component: CountryViewComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [CountryViewComponent]
})
export class AfricaModule { }
```

**Child Component Service file**

country-view-http.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//importing Http Client to make the request
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


//importing observables related code
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CountryViewHttpService {

  public currentCountries;
  public baseUrl = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
    console.log("Country View Service Called");

  }

  // Exception Handler
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log("Handle error Http calls")
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }


  // method to return single country Informations
  public getSingleCountryInfo(currentCountryName): any {

    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/' + currentCountryName + '?fullText=true');
    console.log(myResponse);
    return myResponse;
  } // end get country info function
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid mainContainer">
  <!--Navigation Secion-->
  <div class="row navigationMainRow">
    <div class="col-12 navigationMainCol">
      <div class="row navigationLogoRow">
        <div class="col-8 navigationLogoCol">
          <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
            <img src="../assets/images/Terra.png" alt="Logo" id="logo">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 navigationMenuCol">
          <div class="row navigationMenuRow">
            <div class="col-6 navigationLanguageCol">
              <p>
                Language
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 navigationCurrencyCol">
              <p>
                Currency
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


// Router Module for Application level Route
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AfricaComponent } from './africa/africa.component';
import { AmericaComponent } from './america/america.component';
import { AsiaComponent } from './asia/asia.component';
import { EuropeComponent } from './europe/europe.component';
import { OceaniaComponent } from './oceania/oceania.component'
import { FilterComponent } from './filter/filter.component';


// import statement for services
import { AfricaService } from './africa.service';
import { AfricaHttpService } from './africa-http.service';

import { AmericaService } from './america.service';
import { AmericaHttpService } from './america-http.service';

import { AsiaService } from './asia.service';
import { AsiaHttpService } from './asia-http.service';

import { EuropeService } from './europe.service';
import { EuropeHttpService } from './europe-http.service';

import { OceaniaService } from './oceania.service';
import { OceaniaHttpService } from './oceania-http.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AfricaComponent,
    AmericaComponent,
    AsiaComponent,
    EuropeComponent,
    OceaniaComponent,
    FilterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'africa', component: AfricaComponent },
      { path: 'america', component: AmericaComponent },
      { path: 'asia', component: AsiaComponent },
      { path: 'europe', component: EuropeComponent },
      { path: 'oceania', component: OceaniaComponent }
    ]),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [AfricaService, AfricaHttpService, AmericaService, AmericaHttpService,
    AsiaService, AsiaHttpService, EuropeService, EuropeHttpService,
    OceaniaService, OceaniaHttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `AfricaComponent` is what you're referring to as the parent component, use the router link like:

`<a [routerLink]="['/country', africanCountry]">{{africanCountry}}</a>`

inside the `*ngFor` syntax.

You've already implemented routing in `AfricaModule`. Now you should be able to get the name of the africanCountry from a router params like this inside your `CountryViewComponent`:

```
let selectedCountryName;
this._route.params.subscribe((params) => {
  selectedCountryName = params['name'];
});
```

BTW, are you implementing `AfricaModule` as a Lazy Loaded module? If no, then call the `forRoot` method instead of the `forChild` method on `RouterModule`.

> EDIT: 
>   You're not able to access the country name because you're trying to access the wrong state param name. You've defined the country name as `name` in your routes config. But you're trying to access it as a snapshot value of `currentCountryName` key which would not exist. Also using the snapshot to get state or query params isn't really a good practice as these might change asynchronously.

**Have a look at [this StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbaayr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcountry.component.ts)**

This should definitely help

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not working. I am getting the error `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'country/Algeria'`
when I click on Algeria. (A country in Africa view)

Comment: Did you change your `RouterModule.forChild` to `RouterModule.forRoot`?

Comment: Yes, I made the changes.

Comment: Can you share the code of the template where your `router-outlet` is? I think this is because the `:name` part should be defined as a child path in the children section of the `country` path.

Comment: I am not sure that if this is what you are looking for (since I am still in the learning phase)  but I have updated my question. Please, have a look.

Comment: Have a look at the Updated Answer. I've created a StackBlitz project to help you check where exactly the issue is with your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been trying this since afternoon. :)
But one thing though, We do we need to include the route in app.module.ts?
I know, it's late but since you have helped so much. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178225/discussion-between-abhinav-alok-and-siddharth-ajmera).